# EXCEL: How to jump to first (or next) duplicate value in a sorted column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, search, microsoft-excel-2016, duplicate

I have a sheet with hundreds of thousands of rows.  There are a few duplicates on the ID column.  The technique to highlight duplicates does not work, as using the scroll bar shoots past them so fast that you can't identify them (it is skipping many hundreds of records at a time).

How do I get Excel to place the cursor on the first, or next, duplicate value in a sorted column?

Windows 10; MS Excel 2016

Comment: look here: https://exceljet.net/formula/flag-first-duplicate-in-a-list

Comment: Once you have the duplicates marked using @boboes reference, you can find the row number of the first duplicate with =MATCH("x",B:B,0) in any unused cell.  (B:B is the column with the x's. Replace B:B with the correct column.) Then you can quickly [jump to that row](https://sebastian.expert/find-and-go-to-a-specific-row-number-in-excel/) and delete it.  Repeat until Match() returns #N/A